# How to use the return of a cloud function in realtime databse [Firebase]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Realtime database from Firebase.

I have a cloud function in my index.js that returns an object:

```
{"state":"create","users":["user1","user2"]}
```

I would like to get it from my java code to use it later but I don't know how to proceed..

Here is my cloud function:

```
exports.getProductTypeUpdate = functions.database
.ref("Products/{product}/type")
.onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
  // on récupère le type du produit
  const type = snapshot.after.val();
  // on récupère les utilisateurs interresse par le type d'objet
  admin.database().ref("Notif/type/" + type)
      .once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        const users = snapshot.val();
        // Retourne les utilisateurs à notifier et l'état de la requête
        const result = {state: "update", users: users};
        console.log("Le résultat final est: " + JSON.stringify(result));
        return result;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        return false;
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a cloud function in my index.js that returns an object... I
> would like to get it from my java code to use it later.

All Realtime Database Cloud Functions are [**backgound triggered**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) Cloud Functions (incl. `.onUpdate`) which means that they don't communicate with any other component of your application (e.g. you Android front-end app or a server you own running java code).

If you want to send back the result of the Cloud Function to your Android front-end application, there are several possibilities, depending on your exact business case:

- Call a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) from your Android application, which does the write to the RTDB and returns back the result (preferred approach IMHO);
- Set a listener to the node of the RTDB node on which you write the result (note that it will cost one write).

---

Side note: I suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/.

In particular the videos explain why you must return the Promise chain in your Cloud Function:

```
exports.getProductTypeUpdate = functions.database
.ref("Products/{product}/type")
.onUpdate((snapshot, context) => {
  // on récupère le type du produit
  const type = snapshot.after.val();
  // on récupère les utilisateurs interresse par le type d'objet
  return admin.database().ref("Notif/type/" + type)   // <= !!! See return here
      .once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        const users = snapshot.val();
        // Retourne les utilisateurs à notifier et l'état de la requête
        const result = {state: "update", users: users};
        console.log("Le résultat final est: " + JSON.stringify(result));
        return result;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        return false;
      });
});
```

Comment: Ok I've read the docs you sent me and the solution is in there, thanks a lot !